# Using portions of .h files

Tags: c

I have a header file **types.h** with, among others, the type definition

`typedef unsigned short int WORD;`

I would like to be able to use only this definition in my **main.c**.  I'm used to being able to doing this in `Fortran` with

`use types, only: WORD`

Is there a comparable form for this in `C`?

Comment: you could just write that `typedef` in your .c file

Comment: Under the assumption you are not allowed to edit the header, but must use the header's specific typedef, the answer is no.

Comment: @WhozCraig, that is my situation.

Comment: As I suspected, the answer stands. No, there isn't a way to do it unless the original header (the one you cannot touch) is written in such a fashion as to enable/disable including certain features via preprocessor flags *you* define prior to including the header. It doesn't sound like it is, and if not, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this in your header file:

```
#ifdef _MY_FLAG
typedef unsigned short int WORD;
//other code needed
#else
//things you don't want
#endif
```

Include the header file in your `.c` file with `#include "types.h"`

Then compile your code with `_MY_FLAG` defined

Comment: This would work if the header wasn't shared.  This is probably the best bet in general, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just include your header file and use the `typedef`:

```
// types.h

#ifdef FlagTypes
    typedef unsigned short int WORD;
#endif
```

```
// main.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include "types.h" // That header file of yours

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Define FlagTypes so you can use the one
       that belongs in header file types.h and do
       something with your typedef WORD... */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the header file contains other typedefs that cause conflicts?

Comment: That is the case for me, though I can just as easily rename said conflicts.  I just wondered if there was a lazier/easier workaround.

Comment: You can wrap them in `#ifdef`'s or just rename them, it's just `C`. But if you were using `C++` you could've used namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you wouldn't just want to include the header?

std library headers have all sorts of crazy preprocessors to make sure that the types are constructed in an appropriate way...

like it could be...

```
#ifdef LLP64
    typedef long long my64
#else  
    typedef long my64
#endif
```

I think you generally just want to include the whole header, perhaps you are doing something against C paradigm

Comment: That's possible.  I'm a native `Fortran` programmer, so I'm used to this capability without having to throw flags at the compiler.

Comment: @text58, yeah just include the appropriate header, doing otherwise seems both a premature optimization, and error prone.